# HttpUrlConnection and disconnect the connection

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("GET");

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Tryit\\tryabc.csv");

        int bytesRead = -1;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    outputStream.flush();


    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
```

I want to know that is it necessary to disconnect HttpUrlConnection?

I close the inputstream.Is it enough or must I disconnect the HttpUrlConnection.And what happens if I don't do it.

Note:The code works well.But I don't put "con.disconnect" at the end.Is it really necessary?

And my program sends request to the same server by this method 3 or 4 times a day.(but not weekends only weekdays).

Comment: All external resources that `implements AutoCloseable` should be placed within a `try-with-resources` statement. Full stop. Your code is wrong as it does not close resources if an exception is thrown. This is part of the contract of the API.

Comment: This is not my production code Boris.In production I close the input and outputstream in the finally block.This is not the question anyway.

Comment: **not `finally` block. `try-with-resources`!!**. Doesn't matter if it's production code or not, not in the slightest, if the API says close then you **must**. What you are asking doesn't make sense - the implementation is platform specific and is predicated on the assumption that you correctly handle resources.

Comment: I use jdk 6.Not try-with resources.

Comment: Support for Java 6 ceased in 2013. Time to upgrade I think...